# GAE: How to find out which requests take a long time to complete?

Tags: google-app-engine

Say that in a Google App Engine application (Java) some requests take a very long time to complete; perhaps some even time out after 30 seconds. Does the GAE Console (Dashboard, Monitoring or similar) provide any way to list the URLs (or any other request properties, such as API method calls) associated with the long-running requests?

Comment: did you check appstats? (don't know your language of choice... here's its documentation for java https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the old Dashboard (https://appengine.google.com/dashboard) provides the info I wanted in the Current Load box (bottom left), in the Avg Latency (last hr) column.

Answer (score 1):

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

> The Python SDK includes the Appstats library used for profiling the
>   RPC (Remote Procedure Call) performance of your application. An App
>   Engine RPC is a roundtrip network call between your application and an
>   App Engine Service API. For example, all of these API calls are RPC
>   calls:
>
> Datastore calls such as ndb.get_multi(), ndb.put_multi(), or
>   ndb.gql(). Memcache calls such as memcache.get(), or
>   memcache.get_multi(). URL Fetch calls such as urlfetch.fetch(). Mail
>   calls such as mail.send().